# WiFi not being detected on Ubuntu 14.04 on a HP Laptop

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

I'm facing an issue with the WiFi. I am not able to connect to any WiFi network nor my Wifi adapter is being listed.

Please do not mark this question as repeat. I visited every answer on the forum but my issue isn't resolved. Hence I raised this query.

For starting, I visited and implemented the best answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers), but still it did not do any good to me.

Output of few of the basic commands:

```
    saloni@saloni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:c2:17:7a:53:e6  
          inet addr:192.168.55.26  Bcast:192.168.55.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6ec2:17ff:fe7a:53e6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34311 errors:0 dropped:298 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21509 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9422260 (9.4 MB)  TX bytes:3237112 (3.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:521328 (521.3 KB)  TX bytes:521328 (521.3 KB)

saloni@saloni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nn | grep Network
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

For the BCM43142 I installed the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package.

```
 saloni@saloni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62
  linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-62-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

The newest version has already been installed. Still I cannot see any Wifi card listed in `ifconfig`.

Also there is no `rfkill` switch for the wireless card.

```
    saloni@saloni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also,

```
saloni@saloni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo ifup wlan0
Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.
```

There are no hardware WiFi enable/disable switch on my laptop. And the WiFi works fine on Windows 8.1 (i am dual booting).

=======

@Pilot6 asked you do do this:

```
saloni@saloni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230] 
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2281]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: saloni@saloni-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2281]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you might have missed to disable the secure boot option. Reinstall the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package.

```
    $sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And the focus on setting the password for disabling secure BOOT.

You then need to restart your system, and press any key to enter into the configuration mode. This screen will only be there for few seconds, so keep your focus while restarting.

You then need to toggle the secure boot option to disable and it will ask for the password you set will installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` package. It will not directly ask for the password, but ask only certain characters of your password,

For e.g.: Enter Character 2, Enter Character 5, etc.

After that confirmation, the system will boot normally and WiFi drivers should be loaded on your Ubuntu.!

Happy Networking!